# same url pattern with differnet views and names

Tags: django

My code is below

template looks like this

```
  <td><button><a href="{%  url 'testschema' allschema.schema_name %}"> Test</a></button></td>
   <td><button><a href="{%  url 'deleteschema' allschema.schema_name %}"> Delete</a></button></td>
```

url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.confighome, name='config'),
    path('<str:schmid>/', views.deleteschema, name='deleteschema'),
    path('te<str:schmid>/', views.testschema, name='testschema')

]
```

views.py

```
def deleteschema(request,schmid):
    some code
    return redirect('/configuration/'+str(request.session["project_id"]))

def testschema(request,schmid):
   some code
    return redirect('/configuration/'+str(request.session["project_id"]))
```

Whenever I click on the Testbutton its actually calling the delete function

Any idea why this happening Since I used named url parameters

Thanks in advance

Comment: The url will always match the second path, since each string that starts with `te` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url will always match the second `path(..)`, since each string that starts with `te` is a string. You therefore better make the URLs *non-overlapping*, as in that no URL that matches the second `path(..)` can match the third `path(..)`. Regardless what URL the `{% url 'testschema' allschema.schema_name %}` thus generates, if the browser sends a request with that URL, it will be matched by the second `path(..)`.

For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.confighome, name='config'),
    path('de<str:schmid>/', views.deleteschema, name='deleteschema'),
    path('te<str:schmid>/', views.testschema, name='testschema')
]
```

or perhaps more convenient:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.confighome, name='config'),
    path('<str:schmid>/delete/', views.deleteschema, name='deleteschema'),
    path('<str:schmid>/test/', views.testschema, name='testschema')

]
```

Comment: then why are we giving the named url in the template .?. I am new to django, so still learning

Comment: @user3048099: to calculate the URL in reverse. But if there is a "collision" that does not work of course. Except for the URL, there is nothing that is in the template to direct it to the proper URL. The name is only used to "calculate" how the URL should look like so to speak.